# Show certain element by clicking anchor

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I show only one input at a time?
For example, if user clicks anchor #3, he sees input with content "1".
My guess was something like this:

```js
$(".unit a").click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass("active");
  $('input').toggle(); // ??
  return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='amount amount-piece'>
  <input type="text" name="amount2" id="amount2" value="7" data-rate="7" readonly="readonly" />
</div>
<div class='amount amount-square'>
  <input data-rate="1.25" readonly="readonly" type="text" value="1.25" name="basket[amount]" id="basket_amount" />
</div>
<div class='amount amount-box'>
  <input type="text" name="amount3" id="amount3" value="1" data-rate="1" readonly="readonly" />
</div>
<div class='unit'>
  <a href="#">#1</a>
  <a href="#">#2</a>
  <a href="#">#3</a>
</div>
```

However it's not working.

https://jsfiddle.net/jjrLgpjp/

[image: example]

Comment: Could you please add your HTML to the question. We need to see how the `<a>` elements relate to the `<input>` in your HTML structure

Comment: Please update your question with your html structure. This would help us to tell you the right way to solve your problem

Comment: Be better action is adding a jsfiddle or snippet on your question.

Comment: you are not selecting your element properly, in order to select just one input field you have to precise which input you want to toggleby using `id` or `data` attribute etc ...

Comment: Post updated, jsfiddle added. Appreciate for feedback!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do it by adding a attribute *(for Eg:* `for="#one"`*)* to your inputs as per the anchor ID and then later select accordingly

```js
$( ".unit a" ).click(function() {
    $( this ).toggleClass( "active" );
   // $('input').toggle();  // ??
   $('input').hide();
   $('input[for="#'+ $( this ).attr('id')+'"]').show();
    return false;
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='amount amount-piece'>
  <input type="text" name="amount2" id="amount2" for ="#one" value="7" data-rate="7" readonly="readonly" />
</div>
<div class='amount amount-square'>
  <input data-rate="1.25" readonly="readonly" type="text" for ="#sec" value="1.25" name="basket[amount]" id="basket_amount" style ="display:none;" />
</div>
<div class='amount amount-box'>
  <input type="text" name="amount3" id="amount3" for ="#thd" value="1" data-rate="1" readonly="readonly" style ="display:none;"/>
</div>
<div class='unit'>
  <a href="#" id="one">#1</a>
  <a href="#" id="sec">#2</a>
  <a href="#" id="thd">#3</a>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! This helped a lot!

Comment: Could you please tell how to show the first input after page loaded and then switching them by clickiing anchors?

Comment: Very appreciate your help!

Answer (score 3):

To achieve this you need to `hide()` all the `input` before showing the one related to the clicked `<a>` element. You can match them up by their `index()`, using `eq()`. Try this:

```js
$(".unit a").click(function() {
  var index = $(this).toggleClass("active").index();
  $('input').hide().eq(index).show();
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="amount amount-piece">
  <input type="text" name="amount2" id="amount2" value="7" data-rate="7" readonly="readonly" />
</div>
<div class="amount amount-square">
  <input type="text" name="basket[amount]" id="basket_amount" value="1.25" data-rate="1.25" readonly="readonly"  />
</div>
<div class="amount amount-box">
  <input type="text" name="amount3" id="amount3" value="1" data-rate="1" readonly="readonly" />
</div>

<div class="unit">
  <a href="#">#1</a>
  <a href="#">#2</a>
  <a href="#">#3</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Another alternative, you can use `data` attribute:

```js
$( ".unit a" ).click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $(this).toggleClass( "active" );
    $('.'+$(this).data("target")).show().siblings().not($(this).parent()).hide();
});
```

```css
.amount:not(:first-child){
  display:none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='amount amount-piece'>
  <input type="text" name="amount2" id="amount2" value="7" data-rate="7" readonly="readonly" />
</div>
<div class='amount amount-square'>
  <input data-rate="1.25" readonly="readonly" type="text" value="1.25" name="basket[amount]" id="basket_amount" />
</div>
<div class='amount amount-box'>
  <input type="text" name="amount3" id="amount3" value="1" data-rate="1" readonly="readonly" />
</div>
<div class='unit'>
  <a data-target="amount-piece" href="#">#1</a>
  <a data-target="amount-square" href="#">#2</a>
  <a data-target="amount-box" href="#">#3</a>
</div>
```